# Regex find a pattern that between 2 strings there are less than 5 words

Tags: regex

Let's say I have 2 strings: "hello" and "world", I want a regex that could find when between these strings (case insensitive) there are less than 5 words between them so:

```
"HeLlo WORLD" <== valid
"Hello this is my world" <== **valid** (3 words between them)
"Hello, this should not be my world" <== **invalid** (5 words between them)
"Shellow: creature in my world" <== **valid** (3 words between them)
```

So far I have this:

```
'(?i)(hello\b{0-5}?world)' <== this is not working
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "No more than 5" includes 5. Why is `"Hello, this should not be my world"` invalid?

Comment: Does `"w:"` count as a "word" in `Shellow: creature in my world`?

Answer (score 1):

Since a word is surrounded by space, we can easily catch a word by the pattern `\S+\s+` then to require it to be less than 5, just limit it to `(?:\S+\s+){0,4}`.

Try this:

```
(?i)hello\S*\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,4}\S*world
```

[image]

Comment: That is not working in SQLite :/ any idea?